# position fixed is not working in ios safari which is defined in iframe element

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, safari

when I open my page2 in iPhone safari the fixed div is staying at the top of the page even if I scroll the page. but when I open page1 the fixed div is not staying at the top of the page, if I scroll the page it moves away.

this is my main page - page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="f1" src="index99.html"  style="border:0;height:-webkit-fill-available;width:100%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the iframe page - page2

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="hello" style="position=fixed;top:0;background-color:black;">hello</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
    <div>h1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the fixed div to stay at the top of the page even if I scroll in page1.

Comment: There is no fixed element in your page 1 html ? Could you provide a working code snippet or a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Yes there is no fixed element in page1. Only in page 2 it is defined. The code doesnt work only in safari browser in iphone.

Comment: "But when I open page1 the fixed div is not staying at the top of the page, if I scroll the page it moves away." - That seemed to be your issue, but as I commented there's no fixed element in your page 1 so what is the problem ?

Comment: Yes I want to set fixed element when I open the page1 it should work same as page2.

Comment: Then set it to `position: fixed` in your CSS ?

Comment: Thats what Iam using but fixed position is not working. the above code is what iam using.